# Vite disk cache issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, rollupjs, vite

I have a project that uses `vite` and `vue 3` for front end. It also uses `eslint`. Sometimes when I run the code, it throws me errors like this:

[image: Vite error message]

`2:26:53 PM [vite] Internal server error:  /path/to/project/wt-frontend-2/src/pages/school-districts/PageSsDetails.vue`
`46:1  error  "@/assets/images/school.svg" import should occur before import of "./components/SdDoughnutChart.vue"  import/order`

`✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)`
 `1 error and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the "--fix" option.`

`Plugin: vite:eslint`
  `File: /path/to/project/wt-frontend-2/src/pages/school-districts/PageSsDetails.vue`

`at formatError (/path/to/project/wt-frontend-2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-76613303.js:36769:46)`
`at TransformContext.error (/path/to/project/wt-frontend-2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-76613303.js:36765:19)`
`at TransformContext.transform (/path/to/project/wt-frontend-2/node_modules/vite-plugin-eslint/dist/index.js:87:14)`
`at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)`
`at async Object.transform (/path/to/project/wt-frontend-2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-76613303.js:36985:30)`

However, once I fix the code and save, it does not detect the updated file. (it does automatically run though).

[image: Updated code]

Is there a way I could resolve this?
I tried deleting node modules and yarn-lock and running yarn to install the modules, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be a [known problem](https://github.com/gxmari007/vite-plugin-eslint/issues/17) with the vite-eslint-plugin.

You can disable the cache in your `vite.cofig` file with the following line:

```js
eslintPlugin({ cache: false });
```